# Specifying linetype in scatter plots of plotly

Tags: python-3.x, plot, plotly, scatter-plot, plotly-python

I would like to specify dotted linetype in scatter plot of plotly

```
   import plotly.graph_objs as go

   go.Scatter(
                    x=df['x']
                    y=df['y'],
                    mode="lines+markers",
                    marker=dict(size=7, color=color, symbol='circle-open'),
                    fillcolor=color,
                    name=f'{study[exp_names[i]]}_exp'
                ),
```

I could specify "lines+markers" in mode. But not sure how to specify the linetype.

Suggestions will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the argument `line=dict(dash='dot')` to `go.Scatter` (as shown in the documentation [here](https://plotly.com/python/line-charts/#style-line-plots)):

```
go.Scatter(
    x=df['x']
    y=df['y'],
    mode="lines+markers",
    marker=dict(size=7, color=color, symbol='circle-open'),
    line=dict(dash='dot'),
    fillcolor=color,
    name=f'{study[exp_names[i]]}_exp'
),
```